# Joint Forcing Extension Property

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing

**Definition 1:** A class $\mathcal{K}$ of countable transitive models of $\text{ZF}$ has strong "joint forcing extension property" (JFEP) iff for all $M,N\in \mathcal{K}$ there are forcing notions $\langle\mathbb{P}, <_{\mathbb{P}}\rangle\in M,\langle\mathbb{Q}, <_{\mathbb{Q}}\rangle\in N$ and $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter $G$ on $M$ and $\mathbb{Q}$-generic filter $H$ on $N$ such that $M[G]=N[H]$.

Also we say $\mathcal{K}$ has "weak JFEP" if $M[G]\equiv N[H]$.

**Definition 2:** A expansion $T$ of $\text{ZF}$ has strong/weak JFEP if the collection of its countable transitive models has strong/weak JFEP.

**Question:** Does $\text{ZF}$ have strong/weak JFEP? If not, is there any expansion of $\text{ZF}$ with strong/weak JFEP? In the other words, can one add strong/weak JFEP to $\text{ZF}$ by adding some new axioms like large cardianl assumptions or axiom of constructibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I note that the strong JFEP is the same as the medium JFEP, since two transitive sets such as $M[G]$ and $N[H]$ are isomorphic if and only if they are equal.

Next, note that the strong property is just too much.

**Theorem.** No consistent extension of ZF, which allows a model to be a forcing extension by adding a Cohen real, has the strong JFEP  or the medium JFEP.

Proof. For any countable transitive model $M$ of ZF, there are $M$-generic Cohen reals $c$ and $d$ such that $M[c]$ and $M[d]$ have no common forcing extension. One can build $c$ and $d$ so that each of them separately is $M$-generic, but the combination $c\oplus d$ codes a real that collapses all of $M$. This is explained in my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143413/is-there-a-forcing-closure). QED

This argument can be generalized beyond the forcing to add a Cohen real to any forcing that allows that coding argument to go through, and I believe this might include all forcing.

**Theorem.** There is a theory $T$ extending ZFC with the strong JFEP.

Proof. Assume without loss that there are transitive models of ZFC. Thus, there is a minimal transitive model. Let $T$ be the complete theory of the minimal transitive model $L_\alpha\models ZFC$. Now, the point is that if $M$ and $N$ are models of $T$, then actually $M=N$, since both must have the form $L_\beta$ for some $\beta$ but it cannot be that $\beta\gt\alpha$ and so both are equal to the minimal transitive model itself. Since $M=N$, of course it follows that they have a common forcing extension. QED

This idea seems to generalize to many other theories.

Meanwhile, it is easy to get the weak JFEP.

**Theorem.** Every complete theory trivially has the weak JFEP.

Proof. If $T$ is complete and $M,N\models T$, then they are already elementarily equivalent and they are forcing extensions of themselves by trivial forcing. QED

Comment: Thank you Joel. I will edit the triviality on Medium JFEP. My emphasis in this question is on searching for some expansion of $\text{ZF}$ with strong/weak JFEP.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it is consistent that $\sf ZFC$ doesn't have weak JFEP either. Suppose that there are exactly two different height of transitive models, that is some $\alpha<\beta$ such that $L_\alpha$ and $L_\beta$ are both countable transitive models of $\sf ZFC$.

In $L_\beta$ we have that $L_\alpha$ is a countable transitive model, so in $L_\beta$ there exists a transitive countable model of $\sf ZFC$, whereas in $L_\alpha$ there are no transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ at all. Since the models agree on $\omega$, they also agree on the theory they think is $\sf ZFC$.

Since we cannot add a countable transitive model of $L_\alpha$ by forcing, and we cannot destroy the fact that $L_\alpha\in L_\beta$ is a countable transitive model, it is impossible for any $L_\alpha[G]$ and $L_\beta[H]$ to be elementary equivalent.

---

Note that it is consistent that $\sf ZFC$ doesn't have transitive models at all, in which case it has strong JFEP trivially.